# How to use properties of JSON without causing an error

Tags: javascript, json, promise

I am calling a fetch on the backend, and am struggling to use the JSON data from it without causing an error.

This is the fetch, which works fine and returns a JSON if I remove the problematic line below.

```
fetch("https://dash.stannp.com/api/v1/postcards/create?api_key=" + secret + "&", requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(result => {
        let item = result
        console.log("item: " + item)
        //this line causes an error
        console.log("pdf: " + item.data.pdf)
        return (item)
    })
```

The line `console.log("item: " + item)` logs this:

```
item: {
    "success":true,
    "data": {
         "pdf": "https:\/\/dash.stannp.com\/api\/v1\/storage\/get\/rum\/1588348478\/pdf-samples\/7476-cda247f3-c634-43bf-8d03-731908549fb1-A6-4add27e8-b08f-4495-846b-7d904e.pdf",
         "id":"0",
         "created":"2020-05-01T15:54:38+00:00",
         "format":"A6",
         "cost":"0.59"
    }
}
```

so far so good, but then the line `console.log("pdf: " + item.data.pdf)`, which is immediately after the first returns an error.

What am I doing wrong, and what do I need to do to be able to use the pdf?

In case it's relevant I think I have some issues with promises, as the return fires before the fetch is completed.

The full code incase if it is helpful:

```
export function previewStannpSingleCard2(card) {
    return getSecret("stannp_API")
        .then((secret) => {
            var myHeaders = {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }

            var myBody = JSON.stringify({
                "size": "A6",
                "test": "true",
                "template": "69185",
                "front": card.front,
                "recipient": {
                    "lastname": card.recipient,
                    "address1": card.address1,
                    "address2": card.address2,
                    "town": card.town,
                    "postcode": card.postcode,
                    "country": card.country, //NB GB / US
                    "author_1": card.author1,
                    "author_2": card.author2,
                    "author_3": card.author3,
                    "author_4": card.author4,
                    "author_5": card.author5,
                    "signature": card.fullSignature,
                    "small_signature": card.smallSignature,
                    "text_block_1": card.textBlock1,
                    "text_block_2": card.textBlock2,
                    "text_block_3": card.textBlock3,
                    "text_block_4": card.textBlock4,
                    "text_block_5": card.textBlock5,
                    "title_text_1": card.titleText1,
                    "fancy_text_1": card.fancyText1,
                    "left_heading_1": card.leftHeading1,
                    "right_heading_1": card.rightHeading1,
                    "right_block_2": card.rightBlock2
                }
            })

            var requestOptions = {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: myHeaders,
                body: myBody,
                redirect: 'follow'
            };

            fetch("https://dash.stannp.com/api/v1/postcards/create?api_key=" + secret + "&", requestOptions)
                .then(response => response.text())
                .then(result => {
                    let item = result
                    console.log("item: " + item)
                    //console.log("pdf: " + item.data.pdf)
                    return (item)
                })
                .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
         })
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Because you are using text and not json

Comment: ... see ... [fetch and `response.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json#Example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your code closely

```
.then(response => response.text())
```

You are telling it to give you text, but you are using it as JSON.

```
.then(response => response.json())
```